# Powershell - XML source separation and customised descriptive preview for checkedlistbox list

Tags: xml, powershell, match, filenames, checkedlistbox

I've written a script which reads a configuration groups XML file, creates an array for both the name and description values and populates a checkedlistbox with the names.  Upon selection of an item the description text box is updated (from the hash) accordingly.  This works but is not ideal.

I'm coming unstuck when trying to enhance the form in two ways:
 1) Splitting the XML file into multiple files (but retain the ability for one file to contain multiple configurations) so they can be managed individually and 
 2) Enhance the description text box so that it now contains the full content of the appropriate XML node displayed in a section-less INI style of NodeName=Value.  Where a node contains multiple values I'd like the values to be comma separated.

I'm some way into the next phase as you can see when you replace:
 a) the call to ReadCfgGroupsFile with ReadConfigurationGroupsFiles in the main script body and
 b) the call to ftnUpdateCfgGroupDescription with ftnUpdateConfigurationGroupDescription in 
    clb_CC_CfgGroups.Add_SelectedIndexChanged 
...but am stuck on ReadConfigurationGroupsFiles and suspect that I will be with ftnUpdateConfigurationGroupDescription when it comes into play with the resolution of ReadConfigurationGroupsFiles.

Please can somebody assist?

Many thanks,

Shaun

Here is the script:

```
    function ReadCfgGroupsFile ()
    {
        [array] $script:CfgGroupNames = $null
        [array] $script:CfgGroupDescriptions = $null
        #[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("CfgGroupsFilePath=" + $CfgGroupsFilePath, $ScriptTitle)
        $FileExists = Test-Path $CfgGroupsFilePath
        if ($FileExists -eq $true) {
            $script:xmlCfgGroups.Load($CfgGroupsFilePath)  
            $xml_CfgGroups = $script:xmlCfgGroups.SelectNodes("/ConfigurationGroup/Group")
            ForEach ($CfgGroup in $xml_CfgGroups) {
                [array] $script:CfgGroupNames += $CfgGroup.Name
                [array] $script:CfgGroupDescriptions += $CfgGroup.Description
            }
        }
    }

    function BuildForm
    # Build the main graphical user interface form
    {
        # Declare objects
        $frm_BuildConfigurator = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $btn_Cancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $gb_CC_CfgGroups = New-Object Windows.Forms.GroupBox
        $clb_CC_CfgGroups = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
        $gb_CCF_Description = New-Object Windows.Forms.GroupBox
        $tb_CCF_Description = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

        #Build the form
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.Text = "Build Configurator"
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.Width = 380
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.Height = 360
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.FormBorderStyle = "FixedSingle"
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.ControlBox = $false
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.Controls.Add($btn_Cancel)
        #Set default button behaviour
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.KeyPreview = $True
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") {$frm_BuildConfigurator.Close()}})
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") {$frm_BuildConfigurator.Close()}})
        # Create the Cancel button
        $btn_Cancel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,305)
        $btn_Cancel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55,23)
        $btn_Cancel.Text = "Cancel"
        $btn_Cancel.Add_Click({$frm_BuildConfigurator.Close()})
        # Create the CfgGroups form elements
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.Controls.Add($gb_CC_CfgGroups)
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.Controls.Add($gb_CCF_Description)
        # Create the CfgGroups group box
        $gb_CC_CfgGroups.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode]::OnValidation
        $gb_CC_CfgGroups.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,6)
        $gb_CC_CfgGroups.Name = "gb_CC_CfgGroups"
        $gb_CC_CfgGroups.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,132)
        $gb_CC_CfgGroups.Text = "Configuration Groups"
        $gb_CC_CfgGroups.Controls.Add($clb_CC_CfgGroups)
        $clb_CC_CfgGroups.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 11,16
        $clb_CC_CfgGroups.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,110)
        $clb_CC_CfgGroups.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ftnUpdateCfgGroupDescription})
        #$clb_CC_CfgGroups.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ftnUpdateConfigurationGroupDescription})
        ForEach ($Item in $script:CfgGroupNames) { $clb_CC_CfgGroups.Items.Add($Item) | Out-Null }
        # Create the Description group box
        $gb_CCF_Description.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode]::OnValidation
        $gb_CCF_Description.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,146)
        $gb_CCF_Description.Name = "gb_CCF_Description"
        $gb_CCF_Description.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,145)
        $gb_CCF_Description.Text = "Description"
        $gb_CCF_Description.Controls.Add($tb_CCF_Description)
        $tb_CCF_Description.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(11,17)
        $tb_CCF_Description.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(330,120)
        $tb_CCF_Description.TabIndex = 7
        $tb_CCF_Description.Text = ""
        $tb_CCF_Description.Multiline = $true
        #Show the Form
        $frm_BuildConfigurator.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    }

    function ftnUpdateCfgGroupDescription()
    {
        $tb_CCF_Description.Text = $script:CfgGroupDescriptions[$clb_CC_CfgGroups.SelectedIndex]
    }

    function ReadConfigurationGroupsFiles ()
    {
        [array] $script:ConfigurationGroupsFiles = $null
        $xml_ConfigurationGroups = $null
        $filter = 'CfGrp_'
        Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptDir | Where-Object { $_.FullName -match $filter } | ForEach-Object { 
            [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName;
            $innerel += $xml.selectnodes("/*/*")
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("_.FullName=" + $_.FullName, $ScriptTitle)
        }
        foreach ($inone in $innerel) {
            $inone = $xmldoc.importnode($inone, $true)
            $rootnode.appendchild($inone)
        }
    }

    function ftnUpdateConfigurationGroupDescription ()
    {
        $tb_CCF_Description.Text = { $script:xmlConfigurationGroups.ConfigurationGroup.Group.($clb_CC_Cfg_Groups.SelectedItem) | ForEach $_ '[0]=[1]`n' }
    }

    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

    $script:xmlCfgGroups = $null; $script:xmlCfgGroups = New-Object -TypeName XML
    $script:xmlConfigurationGroups = $null; $script:xmlConfigurationGroups = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument

    $ScriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    $ScriptDir = Split-Path -parent $ScriptPath
    $CfgGroupsFilePath = $ScriptDir + "\CfgGroups.xml"
    $BuildScriptStr = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition #Full path  - for script name only use $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name

    ReadCfgGroupsFile

    #ReadConfigurationGroupsFiles

    BuildForm
```

Here is the initial combined XML data file, CfgGroups.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ConfigurationGroup>
        <Group Name="Group1">
            <Description>Group1 information.</Description>
            <Features>BITS</Features>
            <IPAddress>10.9.193</IPAddress>
            <SubnetMask>255.255.255.0</SubnetMask>
            <Gateway>10.9.101.1</Gateway>
            <DNS1>10.9.193.11</DNS1>
            <DNS2>10.9.193.12</DNS2>
        </Group>
        <Group Name="Group2">
            <Description>Group2 information.</Description>
            <Features>Net-Framework-Core,RDS-RD-Server,</Features>
            <IPAddress>10.251.120</IPAddress>
            <SubnetMask>255.255.255.0</SubnetMask>
            <Gateway>10.251.96.1</Gateway>
            <DNS1>10.251.120.11</DNS1>
            <DNS2>10.251.120.12</DNS2>
        </Group>
    </ConfigurationGroup>
```

and the following are two split instances which I'd like to use going forwards.

CfGrp_Group1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ConfigurationGroup>
    <Group Name="Group1a">
        <Description>Group1a information.</Description>
        <Features>BITS</Features>
        <IPAddress>10.9.193</IPAddress>
        <SubnetMask>255.255.255.0</SubnetMask>
        <Gateway>10.9.101.1</Gateway>
        <DNS1>10.9.193.11</DNS1>
        <DNS2>10.9.193.12</DNS2>
    </Group>
    <Group Name="Group1b">
        <Description>Group1b information.</Description>
        <Features>Net-Framework-Core,RDS-RD-Server,</Features>
        <IPAddress>10.251.120</IPAddress>
        <SubnetMask>255.255.255.0</SubnetMask>
        <Gateway>10.251.96.1</Gateway>
        <DNS1>10.251.120.11</DNS1>
        <DNS2>10.251.120.12</DNS2>
    </Group>
</ConfigurationGroup>
```

and CfGrp_Group2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ConfigurationGroup>
    <Group Name="Group2">
        <Description>Group2 information.</Description>
        <Features>Net-Framework-Core,RDS-RD-Server,GPMC,Web-Server,Web-Asp-Net,Web-Net-Ext,Web-Mgmt-Console,RSAT-AD-PowerShell</Features>
        <IPAddress>10.10.254</IPAddress>
        <SubnetMask>255.255.255.0</SubnetMask>
        <Gateway>10.10.1.254</Gateway>
        <DNS1>10.10.1.2</DNS1>
        <DNS2>10.10.1.3</DNS2>
    </Group>
</ConfigurationGroup>
```